# longhand bubble sort of 2d array python problem

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array which i took from a text file, within the array is:

```
[('Sammy', 'sammy@gmail.com', '72'), ('John', 'john@gmail.com', '33'), ('Felix', 'felix@gmail.com', '89'), ('Henry', 'henry@gmail.com', '23'), ('Steven', 'steven@gmail.com', '83'), ('Harry', 'harry@gmail.com', '46'), ('Billy', 'billy@gmail.com', '62'), ('Alex', 'alex@gmail.com', '66'), ('Finn', 'finn@gmail.com', '49')]
```

within this 2d array i want to sort the data with those with the highest score at the top of a list and those with the lowest score at the bottom of the list. the list is called sorted_database and is below

my unworking code for the bubble sort is as follows (also i want to do it long hand without using any function e.g .sort):

```
swapped_database = []
def sortdata():
  swapped = True
  length = len(database)
  print(length)
  temp = 0
  while swapped == True:
    swapped = False

    for index in range(0,length -1,3):
      print(index)
      if database[index] > database[index+1]:
        temp = database[index]
        database[index] = database[index+1]
        database[index + 1] = temp
        swapped = True
  swapped_database.append(database)
  print(swapped_database)
sortdata()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you step by 3? That ain't bubble sort. Every tuple is at its proper, consecutive index, and you want to visit each tuple. The size of the tuple has nothing to do with the index of the overall list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The inner loop should not make steps of 3. The tuple size is unrelated to the index at which that tuple resides in the `database` list. A `database[index]` value is a *tuple*, not a *member* of a tuple.
- The comparison should be made on the score. This means you should explicitly compare the *third* element of the tuples, **and** convert them to number -- as they are strings.
- `swapped_database` has no role to play here. Bubble sort is an *inplace* sorting algorithm, so it makes `database` itself sorted. Moreover, `swapped_database.append(database)` makes little sense. It makes `database` an entry inside `swapped_database`

Some other remarks on the code:

- Avoid mutating global variables, so pass `database` as argument to your function.
- In Python, you don't need a `temp` variable to swap values. Use tuple assignment instead.
- `while swapped == True` is overkill, as `swapped` is already a boolean value, so just do `while swapped`

```
def sortdata(database):
  swapped = True
  length = len(database)
  while swapped == True:
    swapped = False
    for index in range(0,length -1):
      if int(database[index][2]) < int(database[index+1][2]):
        database[index], database[index+1] = database[index+1], database[index]
        swapped = True
```

Example use:

```
sortdata(database)
for entry in database:
    print(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach looks overly complicated with the `swapped` boolean and the step by `3`. You can simply use a double `for` loop instead.

Here's a working implementation that returns the sorted list. It uses two `for` loops for swapping, and compares values based on the integer value of the third element in each tuple (rather than doing direct tuple comparison):

```py
def sortdata(database):
  for iter_idx in range(len(database)):
      for elem_idx in range(len(database) - iter_idx - 1):
          if int(database[elem_idx][2]) > int(database[elem_idx + 1][2]):
              database[elem_idx], database[elem_idx + 1] = \
                  database[elem_idx + 1], database[elem_idx]
  return database
```

With the sample data, calling `print(sortdata(database))` outputs:

```py
[[('John', 'john@gmail.com', '33'),
 ('Sammy', 'sammy@gmail.com', '72'),
 ('Felix', 'felix@gmail.com', '89'),
 ('Henry', 'henry@gmail.com', '23'),
 ('Steven', 'steven@gmail.com', '83'),
 ('Harry', 'harry@gmail.com', '46'),
 ('Billy', 'billy@gmail.com', '62'),
 ('Alex', 'alex@gmail.com', '66'),
 ('Finn', 'finn@gmail.com', '49')]]
```

Make sure that you pass `database` in as a parameter to the function. The upper bound to the second `for` loop is `iter_idx` as a suggested optimization by [Mushroomator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487348/mushroomator).